# Update Python sub-version in conda base

Tags: python, conda

I currently have Python 3.8.12 installed. I've been advised to update to 3.8.18 as there are security vulnerabilities in the older versions. I know that updating to a later full release in the base environment is a bad idea, but surely it must be possible to update through 3.8.x versions? However `sudo apt install python3` just returns `python3 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04)` and `conda update python` just returns

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): - WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

So it seems to think that it's fully up to date, but it's still on a version that's a couple of years old.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install python3=3.8.18`?

Comment: Doesn't work `E: Version '3.8.18' for 'python3' was not found`

Comment: @not_speshal Ah! No, don't even consider changing the system Python version on Debian. It can break the OS. Anyway, that technique wouldn't work anyway since the `python3` package is tied to a minor version, i.e. 3.10 here.

Comment: Do you have the base env activated?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to use APT to manage your conda environment in the first place, but I'm not a Conda expert. (Maybe there's an option that lets you tie an env to an external Python executable? IDK.) Anyway, have you tried `sudo apt upgrade python3.8`? Like I wrote above, the `python3` package is set at a particular minor version for the OS.

Comment: What you're calling the "sub-version" is called the "patch version" in [Semantic Versioning](//semver.org) or "micro version" [in Python](//docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info). It is possible to update it in Conda and the relevant docs are here: [Updating or upgrading Python](//conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python)

Comment: Possibly, your env specifies Python 3.8.12 (maybe by accident). Check with `conda env export --from-history | grep python`.

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to update the patch level, from 3.8.12 to 3.8.18 as I've been told there are potential vulnerabilities in the older patches. `conda update python` just says that `# All requested packages already installed.`, but `python3 -V` (in the base environment) is still showing the version as 3.8.12. `conda env export --from-history | grep python` just returns:

`- python - python-gmsh`

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error in Mac OS 2020 intel terminal, but it got solved using below command

```
conda clean --all
conda update conda
#or conda update -n base -c defaults conda #recommended
```